# How do I add headers to firebase web app to issue GET request to external API?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, firebase, http-headers

I'm trying to hit an API with a GET request via an ajax call inside of a react component. I'm getting an error that headers aren't present.

The tech support guy for the API told me to use php to echo the endpoint to grab the headers. I did that in the terminal and got this:

```
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[1] => Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2017 18:53:53 GMT
[2] => Server: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
[3] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.27
[4] => Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
[5] => Expires: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 18:53:53 GMT
[6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
[7] => Connection: close
[8] => Content-Type: text/json;charset=UTF-8
[9] => Content-Language: en-US
```

My app is a simple react app that is grabbing realtime financial data from an outside API. I'm only using my server -- firebase -- for authentication and user data storage. But according to him, since his API doesn't allow for direct client js requests, I have to use my server as a proxy.

How do I do this in Firebase? In my firebase connection?

```
// connection to our firebase database
const base = Rebase.createClass({
  apiKey: string,
  authDomain: url,
  databaseURL: url
});
```

Here's the basic ajax request I'm making in react.
    jQuery.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: apiUrl,
      success: (item) => {
        this.props.addItem(item);
      }
    });

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here's my error:

[image]

Comment: What's the specific error message? Does the API you're hitting support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)? If not, that is the reason the request is failing.

Comment: Thank you. I just added an image of my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making an AJAX request across domains, the host receiving the request must support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). This is done to prevent browsers from fetching content from arbitrary URLs that weren't designed with that kind of safety in mind.

If you control the API in question, you'll need to add a header to the response such as:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

If you don't control the API, you won't be able to make the AJAX call directly and you would instead need to run your own backend code to proxy through to the API. You could do this by, for instance, [connecting your Firebase Hosting site to a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions).

Comment: Thank you. Are the headers I listed in my question the headers that would need to be added to the proxy request? It looks like firebase cloud functions just uses express.js. I'm not sure what I need to include in the request.

Comment: Because you're making the request from a server, not the browser, you won't need to use CORS headers. You should be able to make the request as normal. CORS only applies to browsers making requests across domains.